# Why is TextEditingController always used in Stateful widgets?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

While reading the Flutter documentation, I came across this article that shows [how to handle changes to a text field](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/text-field-changes). What I found interesting is that in this and all other articles regarding `TextEditingController`, the `TextEditingController` is always used in a **Stateful widget** regardless of whether that widget needs to be stateful or not.

What is the reason that `TextEditingController` is always used with Stateful widgets?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Long answer short

You need to *dispose* your `TextEditingController` in [`State.dispose`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/dispose.html):

```dart
TextEditingController textEditingController;

@override
void dispose() {
  textEditingController.dispose(); // You need to do this.

  super.dispose();
}
```

### Explanation

A [`TextEditingController`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TextEditingController-class.html) is a [`ChangeNotifier`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/ChangeNotifier-class.html) as `TextEditingController` inherits from `ValueNotifier` and `ValueNotifier` extends `ChangeNotifier`.

Having said that, `TextEditingController`s need to be **disposed** in order to not leak any resources.
Anytime you want to **dispose** something, you will want to make use of the [`StatefulElement.unmount`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulElement/unmount.html). This is exposed via [`State`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State-class.html) and with that [`StatefulWidget`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html). See above for how to implement this.

---

Ideally, you will set up your controller in `initState`:

```dart
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();

  textEditingController = ..;
}
```